# SQL update - gets an error

Tags: mysql, sql, netbeans, javafx

For a Netbeans project I need to update mySQL database with JavaFX project.
I can add an Account, but I cant seem to edit one.

Here is the methode that gives an error but I cant see what I am doing wrong.
Maybe the SQL syntax is wrong and thats where I need a hand.

```
@Override
public void wijzigenAccount(Account teWijzigenAccount) throws DBException {
    try(Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();){
        try(PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Account SET (naam, voornaam,login,paswoord,emailadres) values(?,?,?,?,?) WHERE naam = " + teWijzigenAccount.getNaam() +";");){
            stmt.setString(1, teWijzigenAccount.getNaam());
            stmt.setString(2, teWijzigenAccount.getVoornaam());
            stmt.setString(3, teWijzigenAccount.getLogin());
            stmt.setString(4, teWijzigenAccount.getPaswoord());
            stmt.setString(5, teWijzigenAccount.getEmailadres());
            stmt.execute();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new DBException("SQLException opgetreden in statement: " +ex.getMessage());
        } 
    } catch (SQLException ex){
        throw new DBException("SQLException opgetreden in connectie " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am new to this so give me a break, I am learning step by step.

This is an image of the MySQL database 
[image]

Thanks already for the help.

Comment: Read the syntax of `UPDATE` at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html. Does your use match that?

Comment: It's `SET col1 = val1, col2 = val2, ...`. There's no `SET (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)`. You're confusing `UPDATE` with `INSERT`.

Comment: Why are you setting `naam` to the same value that you're matching in the `WHERE` clause? That doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is syntax for `INSERT` not for `UPDATE`. Try this way

```
UPDATE Account SET naam = ?,
                   voornaam = ?,
                   login = ?,
                   paswoord = ?,
                   emailadres = ? 
WHERE naam = " + teWijzigenAccount.getNaam()
```

Comment: He did parametrize his query. He just needs to add an additional parameter for the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Barmar - Oh really.. sorry am a DB guy that query looked like it is concatenating string will update

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing ' ' around the name in the update query.

```
UPDATE Account
SET (
        naam
        ,voornaam
        ,LOGIN
        ,paswoord
        ,emailadres
        )
VALUES (
    ?
    ,?
    ,?
    ,?
    ,?
    )
WHERE naam = '" + teWijzigenAccount.getNaam() +"';");
```